# named_scope and HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a models User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :ratings  
  has_many :rated_films, :through => :ratings, :source => :film  
end
```

and Films

```
class Film < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :users, :through => :ratings  
end
```

I am looking to find all Films that have not been rated by the specified user, smth like

```
class Film < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :users, :through => :ratings  
  named_scope :not_rated_by_user, lambda { |user|  
    {:joins => :users, :conditions => ['? NOT IN users', user]}  
  }  
end  

Film.not_rated_by_user(User.first)
```

I am not that familiar with SQL so am not quite sure if this could be achieved in a named scope.

Many thanks

Yuriy

Comment: Long after this was originally posted but there is an answer here that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032194/rails-habtm-and-finding-record-with-no-association

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a `ratings` table, which is your `join` table. Right? So you need something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
   has_many :ratings
   has_many :rated_films, :through => :ratings, :source => :film  
end

class Film < ActiveRecord::Base  
   has_many :ratings
   has_many :users, :through => :ratings

   named_scope :not_rated_by_user, lambda { |user_id| {
      :include => :ratings,
      :conditions => ['? NOT IN (ratings.user_id)', user_id]
   }}
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :film
   belongs_to :user
end
```

And you can use

```
Film.not_rated_by_user(User.first.id)
```

Please let me know if it helped. I haven't tested!

Comment: >> Film.not_rated_by_user(User.first.id)
=> []

Comment: And you're sure there's a `film` this `user` didn't rate, right?

Comment: yes, `User.first.rated_films.count => 100` , `Film.count => 4359`

Comment: unfortunately no, even when I fixed a typo in lamda `user => user_id`