# Rails: HABTM - find all records with no association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 2 models (Workout, Equipment) in a has and belongs to many relationship. If I use `Workout.find(:all, :joins => :equipment, :conditions => "equipment.id = 5")` it works, but if I use `Workout.find(:all, :joins => :equipment, :conditions => "equipment.id = null")` it doesn't return the records with no association. Any ideas?

Comment: Rails join is an inner join. Check out Jamsi's answer for left outer join which will give you the "unassociated workouts".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails habtm and finding record with no association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032194/rails-habtm-and-finding-record-with-no-association)

Answer (score 11):

Give this a whirl;

```
Workout.joins("left join equipments e on workouts.id = e.workouts_id").where("e.id is null")
```

Comment: rails 3 arel: `Workout.joins(:equipments, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).where( Equipment.arel_table[:id].eq(nil) )`