# Ruby: Parent-child association only returns "Object"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying the list my parent and children of my Model "Performance Indicators", in my model I have this for parent/children:

```
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "PerformanceIndicator", :foreign_key => 'parent_id2'
  has_many :children, class_name: "PerformanceIndicator", :foreign_key => 'parent_id2'
```

and in my performance indicators table I have the column parent_id2: `t.integer  "parent_id2"`

But if I try to call the parent like this for example: `PerformanceIndicator.parent`, its returning "Object", and if I try for the children it says `#<NoMethodError: undefined method children' for`

What am I doing wrong?

I want to list the performance indicators something like this:

```
Parent1
  Children1
  Children2
Parent2
  Children1
```

EDIT:

this is my performance indicators model:

```
class PerformanceIndicator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :improvement_actions
  has_ancestry

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "PerformanceIndicator"#, :foreign_key => :parent_id2
  has_many :children, class_name: "PerformanceIndicator", :foreign_key => 'parent_id2'

  scope :parents, -> { where('parent_id2=''') }


  def self.search(search)
    where("name iLIKE ? OR description iLIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")


    # where("description LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider changing your terminology. A child-parent relationship generally infers the child class inheriting from the parent class.

> But if I try to call the parent like this for example: PerformanceIndicator.parent, its returning "Object", and if I try for the children it says #

This is happening because you are actually calling the class method `parent` on your class `PerformanceIndicator`, which inherits from `Object`. thus, the parent class of `PerformanceIndicator` is `Object`.  There is no class method `children` for your class because it doesn't exist.  What you have defined in your class is an instance method.

You must have an instance of your class to call these methods. You can instantiate a new instance of this object like so:

```
pi = PerformanceIndicator.new
pi.parent
pi.children
```

Comment: how should I do it ? I need to list parents and their children

Comment: you can loop them  by doing `pi.children.each`

Comment: but pi = PerformanceIndicator.new just creates a nil. If I call like this  `Performance. @pi = PerformanceIndicator.all` `@pi.parent` returns Object aswell

Comment: well you need to add the associations before you can loop over them

Answer (score 0):

The associations of a model are always per instance.

Therefore, you can't access `PerformanceIndicator.parent` as it is a call to the model itself, but not an instance.

to create proper associations, you have to create different instances, like:

```
indi1 = PerformanceIndicator.create
indi2 = PerformanceIndicator.create(parent: indi1)
```

Now you can access them like

```
indi1.children # => ActiveRecord::Relation
indi1.children.to_a # => [<PerformanceIndicator: id: 2, ....>]

indi2.parent  # => <PerformanceIndicator: id: 1>  alias indi1
```

If you already have a `parent_id`, then you should take away `parent_id2` and change the relations as follows:

```
 belongs_to :parent, class_name: "PerformanceIndicator"
 has_many :children, class_name: "PerformanceIndicator", :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
```

Afterwards, you can create a parent scope:

```
scope :parents, -> { where(parent_id: nil) }
```

And you can iterate through them:

```
PerformanceIndicator.parents.each do |parent|
  # do stuff with parent
  parent.children.each do |child|
    # do stuff with child
  end
end
```

Comment: but how can i loop them? I have them created already with the parent_id

Comment: I edited my post to show you how to setup iterating through the parents and children.

Comment: with that scope it says `stack level too deep`

Comment: can you please edit your initial post to show how your productive code looks like, now?

Comment: its the same, I just edited my model to what you wrote :/ with the belogs, has_many and the scope

Comment: "the same" as before? As you haven't pasted the initial code snippet you are using, we can't see what it looks like.
It would be very helpful to see the entire model code and the method with which you are accessing and using the parent-child relation, so we can have a look on why it is running into a recursive call.

Comment: the same as your suggestion, i uptated the question with my model. I have parent_id2 because I also have the ancestry gem for a hierarchy mode, but I need multiple parent_id option so I was trying to use other parent id for the one with 2 parents

Comment: ah, okay, I got the full picture now. 
You will have to uncomment the `parent_id2` part of the `belongs_to` association again, then. 
And I'm deeply sorry, I just tried it out and got the same problem, because the method `parents` already exists in ruby and the whole runs into an object-recursion. You just have to rename the scope to something like `:without_parents` and should be fine.

One little further thing: your pasted code of the scope says `where('parent_id2=''')` might get you into trouble because of the apostrophe ambiguity. you should change it to `where(parent_id2: nil)`

Comment: okay its working this way :) with this method its possible to have multiple parents ?

Comment: Not really,if you plan on having multiple parents, you will have to introduce an `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation to itself. See this article here for more info on how to handle it: [Bi-Directional has_and_belongs_to_many on a Single Model in Rails](http://cobwwweb.com/bi-directional-has-and-belongs-to-many-on-a-single-model-in-rails)

Comment: i did that tutorial you said, but now I don't undertand how can I list all the parents and childs in that tutorial way ?

Comment: this question has already been answered in other threads, please see the following links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279317/rails-habtm-find-all-records-with-no-association
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165062/habtm-relation-find-all-records-excluding-some-based-on-association