# Finding models that do not have a HABTM relation or at least one that has a certain attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a Rails 5 application, I have two models associated via a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    scope :public_only, -> { where(public: true) }
end
```

The association table is called `users_groups`.

I want to find users that do not belong to any groups **or** belong to at least one group that has the attribute `public` set to `true`.

I can write individual scopes for that, based on [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032194/rails-habtm-and-finding-record-with-no-association):

```
scope :public_only, -> { joins(:groups).where(groups: { public: true }) }
scope :not_in_any_group, -> {
  joins("LEFT JOIN users_groups ON users.id = users_groups.user_id")
  .where("users_groups.user_id IS NULL")
}
```

But I need to combine these. So I tried an `.or`:

```
Users.public_only.or(Users.not_in_any_group)
```

... which raised an error:

```
ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins, :references]
```

How do I combine these two apparently incompatible queries? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742078/relation-passed-to-or-must-be-structurally-compatible-incompatible-values-r), but the example there is a little more trivial.

Comment: @sihck Can you post UserGroup model code ?

Comment: There is no model, it's only an association table. It's a HABTM relationship, thus it needs no model.